# Get list of products with price and special price by category - SOAP Magento

Tags: php, magento, soap

I'm trying to find a way to call Magento with SOAP v1 and return a list of products with the price and special price of the same category but every function I found doesn't return this values, I would need to make a call for each product and it takes a long time.

Until now I tried:

```
$category = $client->call($session, 'catalog_category.assignedProducts', '31');
```

and:

```
$category = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.list');
```

Is there a way?